# drop down value not being submitted to post array

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

Currently working with a php project in which I connect to a database in phpmyadmin. I'm currently implementing my one to many relationship and on one of my forms there is a drop down list with the list of categorys(foreign key) that a product in my database can have, however when I check the post array, and the array that contains all the values for the insert query everything is there except the foreign key.

Drop down list and array of values:

```
 <select name="Category_ID">
    <?php
     foreach ($category as $cat) {
     echo '<option value="' . $cat['ID'] . '">' . $cat['ID'] . '</option>';
     }
      ?>
   </select>


     Array ( 
    [authorName] => Hiroshi Sakurazaka 
    [bookName] => All You Need Is Kill 
    [costPrice] => 59
    [sellPrice] => 99 
    [productCatID] => ) 
    Could not insert book
```

Heres the file that converts the data in the formdata array into an object:

```
<?php
require_once 'product.php';   //Connecting to the product class
require_once 'Classes/productTable.php'; //Connecting to the TableGateway
require_once 'Classes/Connection.php'; //Connecting to the Connection class
require_once 'validateProduct.php';//Connecting to the product validation
require_once 'utils/functions.php';

//start_session();
//
//if (!is_logged_in()) {
//    header("Location: login_form.php");
//}

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    echo '</pre>';

$formdata = array();
$errors = array();

validate($formdata, $errors);

if (empty($errors)) {
    $AuthorName = $formdata['AuthorName'];
    $BookName = $formdata['BookName'];
    $costPrice = $formdata['CostPrice'];
    $sellPrice = $formdata['sellPrice'];
    $productCatID = $formdata['productCatID'];


    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($formdata);
    echo 'Form Data array';
    echo '</pre>';

    $connection = Connection::getInstance();

    $gateway = new productTable($connection);

    $id = $gateway->insert($AuthorName, $BookName, $costPrice, $sellPrice, $productCatID);



    header('Location: viewProducts.php');
}
else {
    require 'createProductForm.php';
}
```

Heres the function in the table gateway that inserts the object into the database:

```
> public function insert($authorName, $bookName, $costPrice, $sellPrice,
> $productCatID) {
>     $sql = "INSERT INTO "
>             . "`product`(`AuthorName`, `BookName`, `CostPrice`, `sellPrice`, `productCatID`)"
>             . " VALUES (:authorName,:bookName,:costPrice,:sellPrice,:productCatID)";
>     $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
>     $params = array(
>         "authorName" => $authorName,
>         "bookName" => $bookName,
>         "costPrice" => $costPrice,
>         "sellPrice" => $sellPrice,
>         "productCatID" => $productCatID
>     );
>     print_r($params);
>     $status = $statement->execute($params);
> 
>     if (!$status) {
>         die("Could not insert book");
>     }
> 
>     $id = $this->connection->lastInsertId();
> 
>     return $id; }
```

can somebody please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you correctly fill array item "productCatID" with POST/GET param "Category_ID" (they have different names) ?

Comment: Yeah theyre correctly filled

Comment: Show us the code that does the save in the database and anything related. From what you've posted so far it doesn't gives any clues on what's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem finally, so I'll post how I did it. For debuging my code and  to see what values were being passed into the `$POST` array and the `$formdata` array, I used `print_r` to post each array if there was a problem and heres what I got:

```
$POST  Array
    (
        [AuthorName] => g
        [BookName] => g
        [CostPrice] => 33
        [sellPrice] => 3
        [productCatID] => 4
        [createProduct] => Create Product
    )
    form data array
    (
        [AuthorName] => g
        [BookName] => g
        [CostPrice] => 33
        [sellPrice] => 3
        [ProductCatID] => 
    )
```

As you can see the `$POST` array was getting the value from the drop down list just fine, it was the form data array that was the issue. Embarrassingly the issue was just a simple typo error that was quickly resolved in my validation script.

Answer (score 0):

With foreach you have to explicitly request access to the key, so if you don't, you'll only get the array values.

Just do this to debug (outside of the `<select>`):

```
foreach($category as $key=>$cat){
    var_dump($cat['ID'], $cat, $key);
}
```

And I think you'll see where the actual data you need is.

(also, you seem to be running without strict errors and notices on, which is crucial for debugging and might show you some notices when array keys you try to access don't exist)

Comment: I added that for each, and when I did only one of the drop down options was available, also can you explain what you mean by strict error notices? I was under the assumption you needed something like x-debug to debug php code

Comment: no, in php.ini there's a directive error_reporting. Add E_ALL to that directive and you should start seeing your errors.

Comment: @Jambo As long as you're on php version 5.4+ that'll get you everything, yeah.  (need those uninitialized array key notices for early detection assistance)

Answer (score 0):

Your select has the name of `Category_ID` not `productCatID`.  If you expecting GET/POST data coming in under `productCatID` you need to name your select `productCatID`.

Comment: I changed that awhile ago and the error still persists